# How to integrate TLF 3.0 in to existing Flex 4 or above application?

Tags: apache-flex

Steps which have done with Flex Builder 4.6.1 code application.

1. Replaced 3.0 TLF in Flex Builder 4.6.1 (Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs)
2. Added textLayout.swc into project dir's libs folder.
3. Cleaned the complete project and copied main application's .swf file and pasted into server dir.
4. It is showing blank page, some times it shows Error# 2032

Please guide me to make it working.

Comment: I also tried to integrate TLF 3.0 with Flash Builder 4.0, and created a new Flex application to test TLF 3.0 properties, while running the application getting this error.Error #1014: Class flashx.textLayout.container::TextContainerManager could not be found.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I am trying to do the same.

Comment: You could use Apache Flex 4.9.0, as it was updated to use version 3.0.33 of TLF.